# SVG works different under different cases

Tags: svg, inkscape, coreldraw

ehm, right now I'm trying to vectorize and old logo my friend did for a club at my uni. I have the logo as .ai and find a converter to svg.
When I open that converted svg logo in my browser it appears great.
[Here's a print screen of how it looks in firefox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3P21.png)

Also, when i open the logo on Inkscape, it also appears great.
[Here's how it looks on Inkscape.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArFg5.png)

Nevertheless, when I open it on Corel Draw, it is a complete mess.
[How it looks in corel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NInwg.png)

I found that some of the objects are causing some trouble, the stars and some other things. If i delete them, the logo appears a little bit more understandable in corel, but still doesn't look great. [Logo with less details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JXNC.png)

I'm trying to use the logo to make some banners, posters and things like that, and the printer can't use that version of the logo because they use corel.

Does someone know why is that happening and how to correct the issue?

I'm gonna left the .ai as the .svg in case somebody need them to undestand the issue. [ai](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_EFi_g_mQyJHvLrU7oI8GWF6GLTy1mX_/view?usp=sharing) and [svg.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sXMQtw9c49PgxDHFwskoRhrYpXyu2w9T/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Just a guess from taking a quick scan of the SVG source - it's possible that Corel doesn't know how to render the png's that are embedded as data:uri's - try to extract a small amount of SVG source to test if that's true (I don't have Corel).

Comment: @Jorge Moises Meza Ramirez: ai files contain embedded pdfs. You can open them in free pdf viewers like foxit or exchange to save them as pdf files. PDF would actually be my first choice for printing. Otherwise you could install a free trial version of adobe cc to open/convert the logo in AI. This way you could also tweak some issues like complex gradients. I also recommend to convert texts to paths - otherwise you would see replaced font when exporting the logo to a format other than pdf.

Comment: i did install illustrator through free trial to get rid of the issue. thanks to both for the answer.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions; this would probably fit better on [graphicdesign.se].